# how to prepare testng.xml for calling multiple methods(different each time)from multiple packages multiple times

Tags: java, web-services, selenium-webdriver, testng

my .jmx file will look like [test-jmx file ], we have created different packages for unique names and created testng.xml file as follows.

```html
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="234Login" verbose="1">

 <test name="Login">
  <classes>
   <class name="com.CompanyName.api.test.CompanyNameTestConfig" />
   <class name="com.CompanyName.api.test.auth.LoginTest">
    <methods>
     <include name="check_active" />
     <include name="post_login" />
    </methods>
   </class>
  </classes>
 </test>
 <test name="Default_1">
  <classes>
   <class name="com.CompanyName.api.test.defaultaccess.DefaultAccessTest">
    <methods>
     <include name="get_methods" />
     <include name="get_accountConfiguration" />
     <include name="get_userRelatedLocations" />
    </methods>
   </class>
  </classes>
 </test>
 <test name="Services">
  <classes>   
   <class name="com.CompanyName.api.test.services.UserServicesTest">
    <methods>
     <include name="user" />
    </methods>
   </class>
  </classes>
 </test>
 <test name="Default_2">
  <classes>   
   <class name="com.CompanyName.api.test.defaultaccess.DefaultAccessTest">
    <methods>
     <include name="get_ToDoTaskWithPaging" />
    </methods>
   </class>
  </classes>
 </test>
 <test name="MedicalApptRead_1">
  <classes>   
   <class name="com.CompanyName.api.test.medicalappt.MedicalApptTest">
    <methods>
     <include name="get_AllScheduleType" />
     <include name="get_AllScheduleStatus" />
    </methods>
   </class>
  </classes>
 </test>
 <test name="Default_3">
  <classes>   
   <class name="com.CompanyName.api.test.defaultaccess.DefaultAccessTest">
    <methods>
     <include name="get_WardsOfLocation" />
     <include name="get_RoomForLocation" />
    </methods>
   </class>
  </classes>
 </test>
 <test name="MedicalApptRead_2">
  <classes>   
   <class name="com.CompanyName.api.test.medicalappt.MedicalApptTest">
    <methods>
     <include name="get_DayScheduleFromViewForDoctors" />
     <include name="get_WaitListWithPagingForDoctor" />
    </methods>
   </class>
  </classes>
 </test>
 <test name="PlanRead">
  <classes>   
   <class name="com.CompanyName.api.test.planread.Planread1">
    <methods>
     <include name="get_DoctorInOutStatus" />
    </methods>
   </class>
  </classes>
 </test>
<test name="Logout">
  <classes>   
   <class name="com.CompanyName.api.test.auth.LogoutTest">
    <methods>
     <include name="post_logout" />
    </methods>
   </class>
  </classes>
 </test>

</suite>
```

[JMXFile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TV635.png)
when i run the above test suite from main test suite by passing parameters like username & password, first two methods(check_active, post_login) only running. In Remaining class all the test methods which are not specified as included tag also running. How to run the all test methods which are included in the above mentioned  .xml file in the same order. i did not specified any priority to the test methods. i need to create multiple test suites and need to create main test suite to run all the test suites in order. Please help me in this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try adding `preserve-order="true"` to all your `<test>` tags in testng.xml files